# How to merge old and new values of entity in JPA with shortest code?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, Customer and Address:

Customer Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `encrypt_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `self_description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
  KEY `idx_last_name` (`last_name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Address Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `account_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  -- Office, Branch-1, Branch-2, 
  `door_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `landmark` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(20),
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In Customer.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
private List<Address> addresses;
```

In Address.java

```
Nothing regarding customer, because I am using uni-direction.
```

In CustomerDaoImpl.java

```
public boolean updateEntity(Customer customer) {

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    return false;
}
```

The issue is I am doing update, it is creating new user every time. But I have to update customer and its childes addresses and theme objects.

My request body:

```
    {
      "customerId": 102,
      "addresses": [
        {
          "accountId": 203,
          "addressType": "main office",
          "areaName": "area3",
          "city": "city3",
          "district": "district3",
          "doorNum": "89",
          "landmark": "landmark3",
          "phone1": "646432365465",
          "phone2": "4534542355675",
          "postalCode": "453245",
          "street": "street3"
        }
      ],
      "active": 1,
      "email": "bbb@gmail.com",
      "encryptKey": "wwwwwfsad",
      "firstName": "ccc",
      "lastName": "ddd",
      "password": "user2",
      "selfDescription": "user2",
      "userName": "user2",
      "theme": {
        "themeId": 402,
        "description": "theme2",
        "name": "theme2",
        "categoryId": 301
      }
    }
```

What changes do I have to do?

Comment: You need to get the older Customer entity first then add new data in customer then update customer entity. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a record in database: first you have to retrieve your record from database to the **Persistence Context** then update its columns values. I think you are trying update database records directly and it is wrong. It just creates new object with different id and saves it in database.

```
Customer retrievedCustomer = session.get(customer);

make you changes on retrievedCustomer...

session.update(retrievedCustomer);
```

Comment: can you explain me more detail please.

Comment: In hibernate we just need objects i mean hibernate just knows objects or entities. so to updating a record in database we should retrieve that record as an object in hibernate context then update object's fields and save it again in database.